# Should email addresses be anonymized/pseudonymized under GDPR?

Tags: privacy, european-union, gdpr, data-protection, data-storage

GDPR states recommendation to pseudonymise or even anonymise Personal Data. A lot — most of — web sites and services require email address on signup.

Should, from the Data Controller's point of view, emails be either anonymised or pseudonymised?

To put it simple, **I run a website which stores users' emails; can I store them in the DB in plaintext?**

Answer (score 2):

The GDPR does not regulate *specific* security measures beyond making recommendations about what you should considder.

It requires you to evalute **risks** and, if necessary, implement security measures to mitigate those risks. Doing a DPIA (Data Protection Impact Assessment) to identify levels of risk may be helpful.

To do a DPIA, one obviously need to know the website and what personal data it process. Only you can do that.

As an example, I would say that if you run a website for sharing cupcake recipes, you probably would *not* need to encrypt the emails. If, on the other hand, you run a website were AIDS-patients share experiences, exposing a user's email address to a third part would be very harmful to the individual, and you should probably implement additional layers of security, such as encryption.